# Element UI and font-awesome

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome

Can anyone explane if it is possible to use font-awesome or another big icon font with Element UI? I've seen FAQ but cannot make it work for me.
 https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/blob/dev/FAQ.md

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just include those libraries / or NPM them and they work, Element UI has a limited set of icons so I have include vue-awesome (font awesome) but I notice the position of the icons if out a bit so you need some CSS to adjust top margins (I needed -4px) and line them with say button text.

Comment: It's certainly easy to include FA icons throughout your page. However, you're still not able to use these in Element components where 'icon' is passed as an attribute, e.g. the Steps bar with icon:
http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/steps#step-bar-with-icon

Comment: You can include other libraries and name space - the docs have details:

http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/icon

Comment: http://element.eleme.io/1.4/#/en-US/component/icon are the only docs that talk about how to implement 3rd lib for icons now