# How to use Font Awesome 5 icons in Element UI

Tags: vue.js, sass, font-awesome, element-ui

I've been using Element-UI for a few days in one of my Vue projects, and today I came to the realization that the collection of icons offered by the framework is very lacking. I looked for a way to add FontAwesome 5 to the project, and I followed the links and instructions available here: [Element-UI and Font Awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649614/element-ui-and-font-awesome/44902895#44902895).

Unfortunately, that didn't work. The instructions are for an older version of Font Awesome and Element UI.

Here's what I tried:

### main.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';
import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2';
import ElementUI from 'element-ui';
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';
import '@/assets/scss/tailwind.scss';
import axios from 'axios';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import '@/assets/scss/main.scss';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = true;

Vue.use(ElementUI);
Vue.use(VueSweetalert2);
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

### main.scss

```
[class^="el-icon-fa"],
[class*=" el-icon-fa"] {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome !important;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

@import url('../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss');
@fa-css-prefix: el-icon-fa;
```

Comment: typo? `@fortawesome`

Comment: @tony19 nope, not a type. FoRtawesome is the group behind foNtawesome. Npm install Fontawesome in @fortawesome/fontawesome-free/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, it looks like the font name is incorrect. Try `Font Awesome 5 Free` instead.

As of now, the documentation isn't very clear on this so here's the method I use. Note that the files you import depend on whether you're using Font Awesome 5 Free or Pro.

*These examples import all available fonts, so make sure to comment out what you're not going to use.*

### Font Awesome 5 Free

Add the following SCSS to your app, e.g. in `App.vue`:

```
// Import Font Awesome 5 Free
$fa-css-prefix: 'el-icon-fa';
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';

@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss';

// Override Element UI's icon font
.fas {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free' !important;
}

.fab {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands' !important;
}
```

### Font Awesome 5 Pro

Add the following SCSS to your app, e.g. in `App.vue`:

```
// Import Font Awesome 5 Pro
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/webfonts';
$fa-css-prefix: 'el-icon-fa';

@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/fontawesome.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/light.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/regular.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/solid.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/brands.scss';

// Override Element UI's icon font
.fal,
.far,
.fas {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro' !important;
}

.fab {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands' !important;
}
```

Now you can use them as icons. Note that the `fas|fal|fal|fab` prefix is still required:

```
<i class="fas el-icon-fa-check"></i>
```

Or elsewhere:

```
<el-input
  v-model="search"
  placeholder="Type something"
  prefix-icon="fas el-icon-fa-search"
>
</el-input>
```

*If you're only using one font,* you can remove the need for the prefix with some additional styles:

```
// Use Font Awesome icons without a prefix
[class^="el-icon-fa"],
[class*=" el-icon-fa"] {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free' !important; // Change this to 'Font Awesome 5 Pro' for pro
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This was a great help.

Comment: Thanks @claviska, can you say what needs to be `npm install`ed for this to work?

Comment: @danbars `yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free` or `npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`